# Weirdness with XDocument, XPath and namespaces

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<kmsg xmlns="http://url1" xmlns:env="url1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://location that does not exist.xsd">
<header>
    <env:envelope>
        <env:source branch="907" machine="0" password="J123"/>
    </env:envelope>
</header>
<body>
    <OrderResponse xmlns="urn:schemasbasdaorg:2000:orderResponse:xdr:3.01">
        <SomeMoreNodes/>
    </OrderResponse>
</body>
```

It does not have any schemas available despite having namespaces specified (I'm getting this from an external source so have no control). I'm parsing it with an `XDocument`, but keep getting `null`s for the items not in the `env` namespace. I'm setting up the `XDocument` like this:

```
XDocument Source = XDocument.Load("Testfile.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager oManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
oManager.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "http://xml.kerridge.net/k8msg");
oManager.AddNamespace("env", "http://xml.kerridge.net/k8msgEnvelope");
```

Then I try to get values:

```
?Source.XPathSelectElement("//kmsg", oManager)

null

?Source.XPathSelectElement("//header", oManager)

null

?Source.XPathSelectElement("//env:source", oManager)

Gets the node correctly
```

I'm assuming this is something to do with me setting up the namespace manager wrong but I can't figure out how to fix it. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In addition to the correct remark by @Mads-Hansen, you have the typical problem of not defining a (nonempty) prefix for one of the namespaces.

**Remember**: XPath considers any unprefixed name to be in "no namespace".

**Therefore this is wrong**:

```
Source.XPathSelectElement("//kmsg", oManager)
```

This XPath expression wants to select all `kmsg` elements that are in "no namespace" and it correctly selects nothing, because any `kmsg` elements in the provided XML document are in the `"http://url1"` namespace, and not in "no namespace".

**To do it correctly**:

```
oManager.AddNamespace("xxx", "http://url1");      
Source.XPathSelectElement("//xxx:kmsg", oManager)
```

Answer (score 1):

The namespace-URI's declared in your source XML do not match the namespace-URI's that you are registering with your `XmlNamespaceManager`.

In your source XML:

1. The anonymous namespace (no prefix) has the namespace-uri: `http://url1`
2. The **env** namespace prefix has the namespace-uri: `url1`

In your `XmlNamespaceManager` you declared:

1. The anonymous namespace (no prefix) has the namespace-uri: `http://xml.kerridge.net/k8msg`
2. The **env** namespace prefix has the namespace-uri: `http://xml.kerridge.net/k8msgEnvelope`

The namespace-uri values have to match, otherwise you are selecting different element names and will never get a match.