# How can I query an XDocument with a 'path'?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

I would like to query an `XDocument` object for a given path, (e.g. "/path/to/element/I/want") but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use XPath with XDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209841/how-to-use-xpath-with-xdocument)

Comment: You can see an example selecting different paths, with / without namespace definitions, etc. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38272604/5838538.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something similar to this might work:

```
var path = "/path/to/element/I/want";
var route = path.Split(new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

XElement result = null;
foreach (var node in route)
{
    if (result == null)
    {
        result = _xmlDocument.Element(node);    
    }
    else
    {
        result = result.Element(node);
    }
}

return result;
```

Comment: `RemoveEmptyEntries` is not a good idea, `//` has a specific meaning in XPath and it's to search all descendants.

Comment: and the condition `result==null` will provide odd results too.

Comment: tried to edit.  Nothing wrong there with the Split given that has nothing to do with XPath

Answer (score 62):

You can use methods from [`System.Xml.XPath.Extensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342747) to do this.

For example, if you want to select a single element, you would use [`XPathSelectElement()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083):

```
var element = doc.XPathSelectElement("/path/to/element/I/want");
```

The queries don't have to be simple paths like what you described, they use the [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) language.

Comment: In 4.5, use System.Xml.XPath.

Comment: @lionheart Isn't that exactly what I suggested? And the `System.Xml.XPath` namespace certainly isn't new in .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 7):

Even though this is a somewhat older post, it should be noted that `LINQ-to-XML` can be used as an alternative to `System.XML.XPath` to find elements based on a path within an `XDocument`

Example:

```
var results = x.Elements("path").Elements("to").Elements("element").Elements("I").Elements("want").FirstOrDefault();
```

Note: The LINQ to XML command may need to be altered to accommodate for the actual structure and/or cardinality of the XML.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675156.aspx

Comment: This makes no sense.  What is x ? If x is an XContainer then Elements is an IEnumerable of XElement and you cannot chain.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to DaveDev but does work, if you do not want to use XPath.

```
public static class XElementExtensions
{
    public static XElement GetStrictDescendant(this XContainer element, string path)
    {
        // todo guard against null path
        var names = path.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (names.Length == 0) 
            throw new ArgumentException("Empty path", nameof(path));

        var result = element;
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            result = result.Element(name);
            if (result == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return (XElement)result;
    }
}
```