# How do I get an IXmlNamespaceResolver

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to call the XElement.XPathSelectElements() overload that requires an IXmlNamespaceResolver object. Can anyone show me how to get (or make) an IXmlNamespaceResolver? I have a list of the namespaces I want to use in my query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) that implements that interface

Use the constructor which takes an `XmlNameTable`, passing into it an instance of [`System.Xml.NameTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.nametable.aspx) via `new NameTable()`. You can then call `AddNamespace` function to add namespaces:

```
var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsMgr.AddNamespace("ex", "urn:example.org");
nsMgr.AddNamespace("t", "urn:test.org");
doc.XPathSelectElements("/ex:path/ex:to/t:element", nsMgr);
```

Comment: D'oh! -Thanks. It's a shame there isn't an easy way to see this from the documentation

Comment: There is no parameterless constructor. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.xmlnamespacemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) article.

Comment: See this answer to another question.

Comment: Yes you can use an `XmlNamespaceManager` but the point is you shouldn't have to.  The `XDocument` stuff lets you just say `XNamespace ns = new XNamespace(...); new XElement(ns + "nodeName"...);` - no namespace resolver required.  Having to then add a resolver is going to duplicate your namespace definitions.

Answer (score 11):

Use `new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable())`.

For example, if you have an XML document that uses namespaces like

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<m:Student xmlns:m='http://www.ludlowcloud.com/Math'>
    <m:Grade>98</m:Grade>
    <m:Grade>96</m:Grade>
</m:Student>");
```

then you can get the `Grade` nodes by doing

```
var namespaceResolver = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
namespaceResolver.AddNamespace("math", "http://www.ludlowcloud.com/Math");
var grades = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//math:Student/math:Grade", namespaceResolver);
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this post while searching on how to use the overload of [XPathSelectElements()] to process a SOAP response so, I will post my answer in case it is usefull for others who have a document with several namespace definitions. In my case I have a document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <queryResponse xmlns="http://SomeUrl.com/SomeSection">
      <response>
        <theOperationId>105</theOperationId>
        <theGeneraltheDetailsCode>0</theGeneraltheDetailsCode>
        <theDetails>
          <aDetail>
            <aDetailId>111</aDetailId>
            <theValue>Some Value</theValue>
            <theDescription>Some description</theDescription>
          </aDetail>
          <aDetail>
            <aDetailId>222</aDetailId>
            <theValue>Another Value</theValue>
            <theDescription>Another description</theDescription>
          </aDetail>
          <aDetail>
            <aDetailId>333</aDetailId>
            <theValue>And another Value</theValue>
            <theDescription>And another description</theDescription>
          </aDetail>
        </theDetails>
      </response>
    </queryResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

To create the [XDocument]:

```
var theDocumentXDoc = XDocument.Parse( theDocumentContent );
```

To create the [XmlNamespaceManager], I use:

```
var theNamespaceIndicator = new XmlNamespaceManager( new NameTable() );
theNamespaceIndicator.AddNamespace( "theSoapNS", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" );
theNamespaceIndicator.AddNamespace( "noSuffNS" , "http://SomeUrl.com/SomeSection" );
```

The names I use for the prefixes ( "theSoapNS" and "noSuffNS" ) are arbitrary. Use a name that is convenient for a readable code.

To select the [Envelope] element, I use:

```
var theEnvelope = theDocumentXDoc.XPathSelectElement( "//theSoapNS:Envelope", theNamespaceIndicator );
```

To select the [queryResponse] element:

```
var theQueryResponse = theDocumentXDoc.XPathSelectElement( "//theSoapNS:Envelope/theSoapNS:Body/noSuffNS:queryResponse", theNamespaceIndicator );
```

To select all details in [theDetails]:

```
var theDetails = theDocumentXDoc.XPathSelectElement( "//theSoapNS:Envelope/theSoapNS:Body/noSuffNS:queryResponse/noSuffNS:response/noSuffNS:theDetails", theNamespaceIndicator );
```

Here is an example program (C#6) using the selections:

```
//The usings you need:
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ProcessXmlCons
{
    class Inicial
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Inicial().Tests();
        }

        private void Tests()
        {
            Test01();
        }

        private void Test01()
        {
            var theDocumentContent =
              @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                        <soap:Body>
                        <queryResponse xmlns=""http://SomeUrl.com/SomeSection"">
                            <response>
                                <theOperationId>105</theOperationId>
                                <theGeneraltheDetailsCode>0</theGeneraltheDetailsCode>
                                <theDetails>
                                    <aDetail>
                                        <aDetailId>111</aDetailId>
                                        <theValue>Some Value</theValue>
                                        <theDescription>Some description</theDescription>
                                    </aDetail>
                                    <aDetail>
                                        <aDetailId>222</aDetailId>
                                        <theValue>Another Value</theValue>
                                        <theDescription>Another description</theDescription>
                                    </aDetail>
                                    <aDetail>
                                        <aDetailId>333</aDetailId>
                                        <theValue>And another Value</theValue>
                                        <theDescription>And another description</theDescription>
                                    </aDetail>
                                </theDetails>
                            </response>
                        </queryResponse>
                        </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>
                    ";

            var theDocumentXDoc = XDocument.Parse(theDocumentContent);
            var theNamespaceIndicator = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            theNamespaceIndicator.AddNamespace("theSoapNS", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
            theNamespaceIndicator.AddNamespace("noSuffNS", "http://SomeUrl.com/SomeSection");

            var theEnvelope = theDocumentXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//theSoapNS:Envelope", theNamespaceIndicator);
            Console.WriteLine($"The envelope: {theEnvelope?.ToString()} ");

            var theEnvelopeNotFound = theDocumentXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//Envelope", theNamespaceIndicator);
            Console.WriteLine("".PadRight(120, '_')); //Visual divider
            Console.WriteLine($"The other envelope: \r\n {theEnvelopeNotFound?.ToString()} ");

            var theQueryResponse = theDocumentXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//theSoapNS:Envelope/theSoapNS:Body/noSuffNS:queryResponse", theNamespaceIndicator);
            Console.WriteLine("".PadRight(120, '_')); //Visual divider
            Console.WriteLine($"The query response: \r\n {theQueryResponse?.ToString()} ");

            var theDetails = theDocumentXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//theSoapNS:Envelope/theSoapNS:Body/noSuffNS:queryResponse/noSuffNS:response/noSuffNS:theDetails", theNamespaceIndicator);
            Console.WriteLine("".PadRight(120, '_')); //Visual divider
            Console.WriteLine($"The details: \r\n {theDetails?.ToString()} ");
            Console.WriteLine("".PadRight(120, '_')); //Visual divider

            foreach (var currentDetail in theDetails.Descendants().Where(elementToFilter => elementToFilter.Name.LocalName != "aDetail"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{currentDetail.Name.LocalName}: {currentDetail.Value}");
            }

            //Not optimal. Just to show XPath select within another selection:
            Console.WriteLine("".PadRight(120, '_')); //Visual divider
            Console.WriteLine("Values only:");
            foreach (var currentDetail in theDetails.Descendants())
            {
                var onlyTheValueElement = currentDetail.XPathSelectElement("noSuffNS:theValue", theNamespaceIndicator);
                if (onlyTheValueElement != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"--> {onlyTheValueElement.Value}");
                }
            }
        }

    } //class Inicial
} //namespace ProcessXmlCons
```