# How to save XML element values to variables

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

Part of my MVC app is a controller action method that POSTs data to a web service and receives an XML response.  I have figured out how to get the response into an XDocument but now I need to go through the info and get some of the node values.  I have been researching, and the closest option I can find it to use XPath.

I am wondering if this is the best way to go, or if you suggest another way.  The XML I am working with will look something like:

```
<HistoryResponse>
  <ResponseType>resultsList</ResponseType>
  <Matches>0</Matches>
  <SessionID>75803234r23df3de</SessionID>
  <RecStart>0</RecStart>
  <ClientCode></ClientCode>
  <Results></Results>
</HistoryResponse>
```

I need to go through, grab the Matches and SessionID and put the values into variables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your xml to dictionary

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring); //XDocument.Load(fileName)
var dict = xDoc.Element("HistoryResponse")
               .Elements()
               .ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => e.Value);
```

and use as

```
string sessionID = dict["SessionID"];
```

Comment: I like this idea, but I am getting a null exception error on the second part (var dictionary = blah blah)  while running in debugger.  Do I need to do somekind of IDictionary<??something> dict = new so on and so forth?

Comment: @teahou No you don't need anything special. I tested above code with the xml string you posted and it works. If you load your xml from file, don't forget to use `XDocument.Load`

Comment: If you are getting a null pointer it is because the top level element isn't named 'HistoryResponse'. Element(<Name>) returns null if it can't find the element. Elements() returns an empty enumeration if nothing matches and ToDictionary returns an empty Dictionary if the source is empty.

Comment: Ntsc - Thanks, that was exactly it.  And thank you all, I have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use **LINQtoXML**. (you need to import the namespace `System.XML.Linq`)

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath(@"../YourFileLocation/somexml.xml");

//you can load the XML from file/stream /string etc...

XElement elem = XElement.Load(filePath);
if (elem != null)
{
   string sessionId=elem.Element("SessionID").Value;
   string matches=elem.Element("Matches").Value;
}
```

If you are getting the XML in a string, you can load that to your XElement using `Parse` method.

```
string xml = "<HistoryResponse><Item>XML Item A</Item></HistoryResponse>";
XElement elem = XElement.Parse(xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

That would definitely work with an XPath expression. Check out [how to use XPath with XDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209841/how-to-use-xpath-with-xdocument) for info on how to do it.