# Write XDocument's attribute value via XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to write an attribute value to an existing XDocument via a given XPath. But it seems the only way to do this is getting an element and then calling the attribute. Is there any way to write a attribute directly (in my case without splitting the given XPath to "/locations/group[@name="Client:UserData"]" for selecting the element and "/@root" for getting the attribute from the XElement object).

given XML (as XDocument):

```
<locations>
  <group name="Client:UserData" root="\\appserver\Data" required="true">
    <path name="some name" path="~\directory\file" required="false" autoCreate="false" />
  </group>
</locations>
```

given XPath:
/locations/group[@name="Client:UserData"]/@root

given value: "\appserver\anotherDirectory"

expected output (as XDocument):

```
<locations>
  <group name="Client:UserData" root="\\appserver\anotherDirectory" required="true">
    <path name="some name" path="~\directory\file" required="false" autoCreate="false" />
  </group>
</locations>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your XPath query, an input sample and the desired output? Can you also elaborate on what you mean by "splitting the XPath"?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209841/how-to-use-xpath-with-xdocument).

Comment: Unfortunately he's using XPath to write elements which is not what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [XPathEvaluate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675.aspx) would solve your problem:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

foreach (XAttribute attr in ((IEnumerable)
         yourDocument.XPathEvaluate(yourXPath)).OfType<XAttribute>()) {
    attr.Value = yourValue;
}
```

Comment: Since XPathEvaluate returns object you can't call OfType<T>() on it. Another cast returns null for attr

Comment: @Tobias, you're right, I forgot a cast to `IEnumerable`. The updated code should work unless your XPath query happens to return a primitive type instead of a node set.