# How to extract connection string from another application's app.config / web.config file in C#

Tags: c#, web-config, linq-to-xml, app-config

I am writing a command line utility which will sit in a web applications's bin folder, and needs to read the connection string of that web application, in order to perform some maintenance tasks on that database.

I have read plenty of examples of how to use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` to read settings from the current application's config file. But this doesn't appear to apply in my case, as I need to read another application's config file.

One way to go is to use `XDocument.Load` which will read the xml file and allow me to manipulate it using LinqToXml. If I have to learn this method I will do, but it will take a little tinkering time to get right.

Is there a way I can take advantage of some part of `ConfigurationManager` to do this?

Both `System.Configuration` and `System.Xml.Linq` are large, and I'm starting from zero - so any hints on how to accomplish this with minimum fuss would be appreciated.

Comment: Think that could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505566/loading-custom-configuration-files

Comment: Thanks @RaphaëlAlthaus that question is exactly what I needed. My question is almost a duplicate except for my additional 'get connection string' requirement, which is no doubt covered in other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the ConfigurationManager allows you to specify the path for a file.

See the following code:

```
private const string configFile = @"C:\Directory\SubDirectory\file.config";

public static string GetConnectionString()        
{ 
    ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = configFile }; 

    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    return config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MYConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Note: Untested and written out of my head.

Comment: This, and the comment by @RaphaëlAlthaus set me on the right path - although the connection string bit doesn't work for me. The last line gives an "inaccessible due to its protection level" error.

Comment: And you're sure the name of the connectionstring does exists in the file you specified ?

Comment: config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString    worked, though not sure why.

Comment: Glad to see that it helped you out. Please consider marking the answer as accepted is this answer was your solution.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178411(v=vs.100).aspx shows the ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings syntax is correct

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution and explanation : [Relocating app.config file to a custom path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838619/relocating-app-config-file-to-a-custom-path) The problem is that using `AppDomain` is a bit more difficult than learning `Linq2Xml`. My suggestion is to just work onthe file as an xml. Beside `Linq2Xml`, there are additional methods to process an xml file : `XmlDocument` and `XPath`. If you only need a few elements from the config file, I suggest using `XPath`, otherwise Linq2Xml is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is only 1 ".config" file for a running application. It is the ".config" file associated with the EXE that started the program.You should probably copy the config values from Another app/web .config to running application.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209841/how-to-use-xpath-with-xdocument). You will find out how to use XDocument to load the file, Linq-to-XML or XPath to find your strings.

Comment: exactly what I wanted to avoid!

Comment: I know, but sometimes we have to use solutions that we're not thrilled about. However, your case appears to be simple, so two lines of code shouldn't present a massive time investment. As Alex Barac already suggested, this is the way to go if you don't want an overkill. I personally would not go through the relocation process because I didn't see the need for it based on your question (the cmdline app resides inside Bin folder)