# Add element to XML C#

Tags: c#, xml

I´m trying to add the following element to a .XML on C#:

```
<Launch.Addon>
        <Name>IvAp</Name>
        <Disabled>False</Disabled>
        <Path>C:\Program Files (x86)</Path>
        <Commandline></Commandline>
</Launch.Addon>
```

With the following code:

```
XDocument xd1 = new XDocument();
xd1 = XDocument.Load(pathToAData + "\\dll.xml");

XElement root = new XElement("Launch Addon");
root.Add(new XElement("Name", "IvAp"));
root.Add(new XElement("Disable", "False"));
root.Add(new XElement("Path", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IVAO\\IvAp v2\\ivap_fsx_bootstrap.dll"));
root.Add(new XElement("Commandline"));
xd1.Element("Launch Addon").Add(root);
xd1.Save(pathToAData + "\\dll.xml");
```

But it throws an error in try {} catch {} block, I´ll be very thankful if you can help me

This is the error:

```
.System.Xml.XmlException: El carácter ' ', con valor hexadecimal 0x20, no puede incluirse en un nombre.
```

Comment: Why you don't want to tell us what exception was thrown?

Comment: I'll be very thankful if you can tell me the error.

Comment: Whats the error from the try catch??

Comment: Hmmm... ("Launch Addon");

Comment: Based on the error message it must be the whitespace character in
`new XElement("Launch Addon");`

Comment: XML elements cannot have a space in it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Still it doesnt work :(. I can´t make it work it writes something different than what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. First of all, as I mentioned in my comment, you need to remove the space from `Launch Addon` because XML element names cannot have a space.

Next, imagine this is your XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
    <addons>
    </addons>
</test>
```

Now you want to add something to it. You need to specify to which element you want to add the new element. So if you want to add an element to `<test>`, then you need to do this:

```
XElement root = new XElement("LaunchAddon");
root.Add(new XElement("Name", "IvAp"));
root.Add(new XElement("Disable", "False"));
root.Add(new XElement("Path", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IVAO\\IvAp v2\\ivap_fsx_bootstrap.dll"));
root.Add(new XElement("Commandline"));

xd1.Element("test").Add(root); //<-- See this, we are adding to test
```

If we wanted to add to `<addons>`, then we would do this:

```
xd1.Descendants("addons").First().Add(root);
```

Or you can use [XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209841/how-to-use-xpath-with-xdocument) to find the node to which you want to add the new node.

Answer (score 7):

Although you didn't gave us the error, I assume that the whitespace here

```
new XElement("Launch Addon");
```

causes the error. Because whitespaces inside tag names are not allowed as far as I know. But check the specs for more information: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar

Comment: Also I am pretty sure this is a mistake as well xd1.Element("Launch Addon").Add(root);