# Namespace of specific XML Node in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, namespaces

I have the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <StoreResponse xmlns="http://www.some-site.com">
      <StoreResult>
        <Message />
        <Code>OK</Code>
      </StoreResult>
    </StoreResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to get the InnerText from `Code`out of this document and I need help with the appropriate XPATH statement.

I'm really confused by XML namespaces. While working on a previous namespace problem in another XML document, I learned, that even if there's nothing in front of `Code` (e.g. `ns:Code`), it is still part of a namespace defined by the xmlns attribute in its parent node. Now, there are multiple xmlns nodes defined in parents of `Code`. What is the namespace that I need to specify in an XPATH statement? Is there such a thing as a "primary namespace"? Do childnodes inherit the (primary) namespace of it's parents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace of the <Code> element is http://www.some-site.com. xmlsn:xxx means that names prefixed by xxx: (like soap:Body) have that namespace. xmlns by itself means that this is the default namespace for names without any prefix.

Answer (score 0):

An example of using an XDocument (Linq) approach:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.some-site.com";

var document = XDocument.Parse("your-xml-string");
var elements = document.Descendants( ns + "StoreResult" )
```

Descendant elements will inherit the last immediate namespace.  In your example you will need to create two namespaces one for the soap envelope and a second for "some-site".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option I found in this question: [Weirdness with XDocument, XPath and namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715936/weirdness-with-xdocument-xpath-and-namespaces)

```
var xml = "<your xml>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // Could use .Load() here too
var code = doc.XPathSelectElement("//*[local-name()='Code']");
```