# Get attribute when it has colon in XML file using

Tags: c#, xml

I met a question that I can't get the attribute in the xml when the colon exists. For example, I want to get the value but it seems not working with my code. Any suggestions?

For Example:

```
Xml content:
<ext-link xlink:href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK154461/" ext-link-type="uri" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK154461/</ext-link>


My code:
foreach(XElement xeTmp in Elementlist)
{
string strValue = xeTmp.Attribute("xlink:href").Value;
}
```

Exception:

```
 {"The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a
 name."}
```

please suggest how to fixed it.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the `xlink:` prefix is the [namespace *prefix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) for the attribute.  A namespace prefix has no intrinsic meaning, it's just a lookup for the namespace corresponding to the prefix, which must be [declared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_declaration) by an `xmlns:xlink="..."` attribute in scope, in this case:

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

Second, the [`XElement.Attribute(XName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute.aspx) method actually takes an [`XName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) argument.  This class represents the combination of an XML namespace and name, thus allowing you to specify the attribute namespace and name to search for using [`XName.Get()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299741.aspx):

```
var strValue = (string)xeTmp.Attribute(XName.Get("href", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"));
```

Or equivalently using [implicit operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.op_addition.aspx):

```
var strValue = (string)xeTmp.Attribute(((XNamespace)"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink") + "href");
```

To loop through all attributes of an element, you can use [`XElement.Attributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292315.aspx).

Comment: get value without pass hard coded value....only pass attribute... hard coded value => ".htttp://wwvw.w3.org/1999/xlink."

Comment: @TeenaRoy - If I understand your comment, `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` is not a hardcoded value, it's part of the full name of the attribute, in the same way that the full name of `XElement` is actually `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`.  See [Understanding XML Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx).  Rather, using the prefix `xlink:` would be hardcoding a value, since the prefix could be changed to anything else and the XML would be semantically identical, as long as the actual namespace is unchanged.

Comment: Hi,  We have many similer cases like "xlink:href", so we would want it to be more dynamic. We tried with foreach loop for the node, but "xlink:href" is not coming when we get the name for the attribute. Is there a way where we can implement loop & can get the complete/full  attribute name as "xlink:href" & then we can have the dynamic implementation in our app.

Comment: @TeenaRoy - you can loop through all the attributes of an element with [`XElement.Attributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292315.aspx), then check the [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.name.aspx) of each.  However, `"xlink:href"` is NOT the name of the attribute.  `xlink` is just a lookup key in the table of namespaces.  The real name is `{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href`.  I don't believe the look-up prefix is captured directly in the `XAttribute`, you might need to crawl up the element hierarchy to find an appropriate prefix.

Comment: @TeenaRoy - It looks like you can use  [`XElement.GetPrefixOfNamespace(XNamespace)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.getprefixofnamespace.aspx) to get the prefix of a namespace.  However, if you hardcode your parser to a particular lookup *prefix*, your parser is essentially broken, since it will fail to parse identical XML with different prefixes such as `<ext-link prefixLookup:href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK154461/" ext-link-type="uri" xmlns:prefixLookup="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK154461/</ext-link>`

Comment: hi can you please tell me how to get "xlink:href" through xpath elements    my code  : var varSearchTerm = from x in xDocFile.XPathSelectElements("//ext-link[@xlink:href]") select x;

Comment: @TeenaRoy - you should ask another question.  The preferred format for questions on stackoverflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735).  But maybe see [XPathSelectElement always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819305/xpathselectelement-always-returns-null) or [Weirdness with XDocument, XPath and namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715936).